# s3 redirect aws javascript sdk. x-amz-meta appended to x-amz-website-redirect-location

Tags: amazon-s3, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to put an object to S3 to redirect. I can create the object without problem however in setting the meta data the 301 redirect is not work. The meta data key is created however this is user-defined and not system defined. User-defined meta data starts with x-awz-meta and system defined data is x-amz.

Therefore the system defined key to redirect is x-amz-website-redirect-location however it seems you cannot create this using the JavaScript SDK. When you set the meta data AWS appends user-defined prefix.

With this code.

```
        command = new PutObjectCommand({
            Bucket: bucketParams.Bucket,
            Key: cliParams.routingRules[0].old_url,
            Body: '',
            Metadata: {
                'x-amz-website-redirect-location': cliParams.routingRules[0].new_url`
            }
        });
```

The key created is user defined as x-amz-meta-x-amz-website-redirect-location.  If I omit x-amz prefix.

```
        command = new PutObjectCommand({
            Bucket: bucketParams.Bucket,
            Key: cliParams.routingRules[0].old_url,
            Body: '',
            Metadata: {
                'website-redirect-location': cliParams.routingRules[0].new_url
            }
        });
```

The key created is user defined as x-amz-meta-website-redirect-location. The key with x-amz-meta does not 301 redirect.

The key needs to be system defined which is x-amz-website-redirect-location.

Anyone know how to set this ?
Thanks

I have tried setting the metadata key to every option. Same result always get a user defined metadata key

Answer (score 0):

This works dont use metadata

```
        command = new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: bucketParams.Bucket,
        Key: cliParams.routingRules[0].old_url,
        Body: '',
        WebsiteRedirectLocation:cliParams.routingRules[0].new_url

    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).